# LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs

Tags: python, hex, aes

I am working with python 3 doing some code for AES and I want to convert string to Hex.

my code

```
   PlaintextString = "secret message!"
   CipherKeyString = "password is here"

  
    PlaintextArray = []
    CipherKeyArray = []

    while len(PlaintextArray) < IOBlockSize: PlaintextArray.append(0)
    while len(CipherKeyArray) < CipherKeySize: CipherKeyArray.append(0)

    for i in range(len(list(PlaintextString))): PlaintextArray[i] = int(list(PlaintextString)[i].encode("hex"), 16)  # 16 stands for HEX
    for i in range(len(list(CipherKeyString))): CipherKeyArray[i] = int(list(CipherKeyString)[i].encode("hex"), 16)  # 16 stands for HEX
```

but I got this error

`LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs`

please help me

thank you

Comment: You have to use one of [these](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) encodings. Evidently, `hex` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

### Conclusion

Use **UTF-8** as your text encoding, and convert string to **bytes** instead of list.

```
PlaintextString = "secret message!"
CipherKeyString = "password is here"

PlaintextArray = PlaintextString.encode('utf8')
CipherKeyArray = CipherKeyString.encode('utf8')
```

You can use subscript to read any byte as an integer.

```
PlaintextArray # b'secret message!'
PlaintextArray[1] # 101(e)
PlaintextArray[-1] # 31(!)
```

### Explanation

To convert string to hex(binary), you have to determine the **text encoding** of the string. For example, it is common to use **UTF-8** as text encoding to convert Unicode characters to binary.

In python3, use `STRING.encode(ENCODING)` to convert string to bytes.

```
'some string'.encode('utf8') # b'some string'
'文字列'.encode('utf8') # b'\xe6\x96\x87\xe5\xad\x97\xe5\x88\x97'
```

The prefix `b` means that the value is **bytes** instead of **string**.

After converting to bytes, you can read any byte as an integer with subscript `BYTES[INDEX]`. Other operations for string like slicing are also available for bytes.

```
b = 'abc'.encode('utf8') # b'abc'
b[0] # 97(a)
b[1] # 98(b)
b[2] # 99(c)
b[-2] # 98(b)
b[0:2] # b'ab'
```